# JQGrid 'Change' dataevent not firing after changing gridrow data inside change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using a dropdown inside my grid. And I intend to change the value of other column based on the changed value of dropdown column. MY code looks like below

```
dataEvents: [
  {
    type: 'change',
    fn: function (e) {
      var row = $("#Grid").closest('tr.jqgrow');
      var rowId = $("#Grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
      //alert(rowId);
      var rowData = jQuery('#Grid').getRowData(rowId);
      rowData.ProductID = e.target.value;
      //alert(rowData.ProductID);
      $("#Grid").jqGrid('collapseSubGridRow', rowId);
      rowData.SelectedOptions = rowData.ProductID + "------";
      jQuery('#Grid').setRowData(rowId, rowData);
    }
  }
]
```

The change event is fired only once for a dropdown in edit mode. If i repeatedly change the dropdown values then the event is not fired. I tried the code without any code inside the change function and it runs fine. After that i found that the setRowData function is causing the problem. If i comment out the setRowData line then it works fine.

I am not sure about this behaviour. Any help or suggestions?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i am using datatype: 'local' for grid.

Comment: I was not able to find out the real reason for this behaviour but i used setCell() function for changing the respective row data and it worked. Please do reply if anyone had anything to add to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

we have got same issues Sorted it out, may help someone, as it's simplistic:

So the whole thing looks like this:

```
{ name: 'STOP', index: 'STOP', width: 30 ,editable: true,edittype: 'select',editoptions:{
                            value: getStopLookup(),
                            dataEvents: [{type: 'change',
                                fn: function (e) {
                                    // var rowid = e.target.id;
                                    var row = $(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
                                    var rowid = row.attr('id');
                                    jQuery(grid_selector).saveRow(rowid,
                                         {
                                             succesfunc: function (response)
                                             {
                                                 return true;
                                             },
                                             url: '@Url.Action("UpdateStop", "Route")',
                                             mtype: "POST",
                                             aftersavefunc:function (response)
                                             {
                                                 ReloadGrid('RoutingDataGrid');
                                             },
                                         });
                                }
                            }]
                        }},
```